# redirect from 127.0.0.1 to localhost

Tags: localhost, redirect

I am running a project on localhost on ubuntu system.It runs finely when I use either localhost or 127.0.0.1. ( That is -  loclhost/myproject or 127.0.0.1/myproject). When I use localhost/myproject and navigate to other pages, say 'contact us' page, it redirects to 127.0.0.1/myproject/contactus. It is not a problem since it displays the page correctly.

when I try to run the same project on another ubuntu system using localhost, there comes some problems. The page is not loading When I try 127.0.0.1/myproject. When I use localhost:8080/myproject, the page is loading, but the css files are not loading since it shows it is loaded from 127.0.0.1/assets/css.

even if I use localhost:8080/myproject and navigate to other pages,it redirects to 127.0.0.1/myproject/page.

I am running a PHP project using codeigniter framework in ubuntu system.

And When I try to run this on windows Xampp, it is redirecting from localhost/myproject to [::1]/myproject, How can I avoid that redirection?

How can I make the page load from localhost only? Please help.

Comment: localhost and 127.0.0.1 are the same thing.

Comment: @Iain Why it is showing different results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think codeigniter does some rewrites depending on your config.

It looks like something is incorrect in your setup.

- Check codeigniter setting `base_url` in `config.php`
- Check `.htaccess` for any mention of domains

[image: config.php]
[image: .htaccess]

Comment: Thanks Bro. The 'base_url' was blank as the screen shot. I added my root url ( http:localhost/myproject) to base_url and it solved the problem.

Comment: glad i could help bro :D